# How to increase the bounty amount?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I asked a question and set the bounty to 50.  Its still not receiving enough attention. So I want to increase the bounty amount. Is there any way I can increase the bounty amount??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the bounty ends you will have the option to start another, higher, bounty (in minimum increments of 50, or higher if you choose).

You cannot change a running bounty.